# element.focus() doesn't work on rerendered contentEditable div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, richtext

[image: Edit little-platform-3291w]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const RichText = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const div = document.getElementById("textarea");

    if (div) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        div.focus();
      }, 0);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div
      className="rich-text"
      onInput={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.innerText);
      }}
      contentEditable
      id="textarea"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: value
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default RichText;
```

I want to implement rich text component, the idea , is that you can type text inside some field , you can style this text ( make it bold, italic, underlined , etc) . I want to same text value inside on `value` state variable , and then wrap it somehow inside of html tags `<p>Hello <b> Andrew</b></p>` , and show it in real time inside the same field , styled. For showing `html` tags inside of `div` , `contentEditable` field, I need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` , and this is the main problem. That on each button press , I update value, component then rerendered , focus goes at the start of field , but I want it to be at the end in time you typing new text . I've tried to make it by `ref` => `ref.current.focus()` , it doesn't work, in code above you can see that I also try to make it by vanilla js with using timeout , it also doesn't work , `autoFocus` - can be used only on `input, textarea, etc` , div can be used with this property . I have save it to `ref` , but then I can't show wrapped html inside of `div` . Tried a lot of cases , but it is seemles . Any ideas how to make it ?

Comment: I know that you tried to use ref but you have some examples at the bottom: https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable

Comment: @AlonShmiel I don't wart to use any library, I want to make it by myself , in this way I just can use https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill )

Answer (score 2):

The issue is when using `useState` hook with `contentEditable` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to sync value. When you type something in the div it rerenders again and brings the cursor back to the start.

You can use instance variables in the function component (`useRef` to update value) to get rid of the issue.

And you should use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` to get the HTML string saved

Try like below

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const RichText = () => {
  const editableRef = useRef(null);
  const { current: value } = useRef(
    '<div style="color:green">my initial content</div>'
  );

  const setValue = (e) => {
    value.current = e.target.innerHTML;
  };

  const keepFocus = () => {
    const { current } = editableRef;
    if (current) {
      current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="rich-text"
      onInput={setValue}
      contentEditable
      id="textarea"
      ref={editableRef}
      onBlur={keepFocus}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: value
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default RichText;
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-knuth-4wvzi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Andrey Radkevich, check this out !!

Comment: value.current = e.target.innerHTML  - here I want to wrap it in some tag , and show it in div on each type => value.current = `<b>${e.target.innerHtml}</b>` , and it showed bold in div . My compoent should work like , you type some text , and some work from this text you want to make bold, you select this text , press bold button , and it showed bold , this is why I need to handle it inside your setValue function , get selected text and wrap it in <b></b> and rerender div , and show it bold , check how rich text works, and you will get the idea , your solution ok , but it doesn't solve my case

Comment: this is why I need some functionality to move caret to the end , on each rerener of div , I need this rerender happens

Comment: I got your use case. You might need to handle cursor position by yourself that  rerender breaks. This code tries to do it => https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/blob/master/src/react-contenteditable.tsx#L9

Comment: Seems like I've found a trick , check answer pls

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return true;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const el = document.getElementById("textarea");

    if (el) {
      console.log(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);

      var range, selection;
      if (document.createRange) {
        //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
        range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.selectNodeContents(el); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
        selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
        selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
      } else if (document.selection) {
        //IE 8 and lower
        range = document.body.createTextRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.moveToElementText(el); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        range.select(); //Select the range (make it the visible selection
      }
    }
  }

  update(value) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    return (
      <div
        className="rich-text"
        onInput={(e) => {
          this.update(e.target.innerText);
        }}
        contentEditable
        id="textarea"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `<b>${this.state.value}</b>`
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: One thing to point out is that after you type into the textarea div, there is a cursor already in there. You can run `window.getSelection` and you will see it's there as a "Caret" type with a range from `selection.getRangeAt(0)`. From range you can call `range.setEnd` to adjust the end point and then `selection.collapseToEnd` to set the focus to the end. This only applies to browsers which have the selection API though. However, you can reduce the manual creation of a range this way for those browsers.

Comment: could you please edit my answer ? @GenericUser, I see some blinking when typing , also should fix this )

Comment: It won't work if you type in the start/middle of the string: the cursor jumps to the end.

Comment: @AlonShmiel, oh , wasn't thinking about it , got it